# CONSTITUENT ANALYSIS OF SENTENCES

Tags: constituents

CONSTITUENT ANALYSIS OF SENTENCES

• Label each constituent at the word level (determiner, noun, verb, adjective, adverb) • Bracket each constituent at the phrase level (NP, VP, PP)

The boys threw the ball very hard.
The playful girls played dolls nicely.
The mother cooked dinner in the huge kitchen for her extended family.
The nice neighbors met the new family in the neighborhood.
The sneaky fast cat chased a scared little mouse around the house.